# How to get the US State Department to authenticate my Federal Tax Filing

Tags: usa, visa, legal, paperwork, certification

I am in the process of applying for permanent residency in a Latin American country.  As part of the process, said LA country has requested authenticated copies of my US taxes for the past 3 years.

I obtained certified copies (expensive) of those tax filings from the IRS and sent them to the State Department.  Instead of authenticating them, the State Dept sent them back with a letter that says "The document must be acknowledged before a notary public".

This seems to violate the basic rule of authentication which is that authentication must happen at or above the same level where the document was generated.

How is some local notary to know that these are valid documents and why would the State Dept not authenticate them directly?

Comment: I am not sure you are asking the right question. Who cares whether a notary public can do anything meaningful? The most pressing question is what this Latin American country is prepared to accept.

Comment: I think the notary is not certifying the document, but that you attest/confirm that you signed the document. One state said that for the state to authenticate a document, the notary's seal would have to authenticated at the county level. I would call the authentication office to get the complete details (since their website is useless). Good luck!

Comment: Did you try calling them?

Comment: Gala, there are generally-accepted standards for authentication of documents, and up to this point, I have been able to get all of of my US documents over that bar: birth certificate, marriage license, diploma, etc.  So I think the most pressing question is why the State Dept is behaving strangely on this one.

Comment: mkennedy, thank you. I am aware of the need to go all the way up the verification chain once I get a notary's seal: its a big pain and that's why I'm irked that State Dept would even try to send me on this pointless, time-consuming "fool's errand".  As to the first part of your comment, sure I could "attest" that I signed the document, but its authenticity is in no way proven by that act.  Only the IRS, together with the State Dept, can duly attest that these indeed were my tax filings for those years.

Comment: littleadv, I called and got basically the same explanation. However, their actions/talk can vary widely.  For example, 2 yrs ago they authenticated non-certified "transcripts" of older tax filings for me, but now they are saying that this was done in error.  Also, this year, they earlier said they would authenticate IRS-certified copies "with a signature of a certifying officer (of the IRS) with printed name as well as their seal and title", but the IRS does not offer that exact certification method, only an "authentic" stamp with a number. So I'm stuck between IRS and State, with no docs.

Comment: @gala: I've responded above to your comments. (Sorry, I'm new at this: just figured out the protocol to tag you.)

Comment: @mkennedy: I've responded above to your comments. (Sorry, I'm new at this: just figured out the protocol to tag you.)

Comment: @littleadv: I've responded above to your comments. (Sorry, I'm new at this: just figured out the protocol to tag you.)

Comment: @owen the IRS does offer that exact certification method. You need to write to them that you *must* have form 2866 when you request the certified copies. See the IRM here: http://www.irs.gov/irm/part11/irm_11-003-006.html

Comment: @littleadv That has the sound of a winning strategy. I will probably try it unless I learn something else. Thank you.

Comment: @littleadv I'm needing a little more reassurance here after spending so much money and time to get nowhere ... How recently did this work for you? Can you put me in contact with an IRS rep who will vouch for this?  Related Request is 4340, which says, _italic_ "If Form 4340 is needed for a court case, mark the “Under Seal” box. Form 2866 will be included only when the “Under Seal” box is checked. If Form 4340 is needed for other legal purposes, mark the “Certified” box." _italic_ But that is not an option on 4506. Is 2866 certif the same as "blue ribbon" (which can't be performed by RAIVS)?